# Meteor Up "This project does not have a .meteor/release file."

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I was successfully using meteor up to deploy my project. However now that I copied all the contents of my project over to a new directory, when I run `mup deploy` I get this error:

```
    Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
    ------------------------------------------------

Building Started: /Users/taylorchamberlain/meteor/dfss
Problem! This project does not have a .meteor/release file. The file should
either contain the release of Meteor that you want to use, or the word 'none'
if you will only use the project with unreleased checkouts of Meteor. Please
edit the .meteor/release file in the project and change it to a valid Meteor
release or 'none'.
```

I checked and my .meteor/release file is exactly the same as it was before. It reads: `METEOR@1.1.0.2`. 
I tried changing it to `none` and `'none'`, and I tried running meteor `update --release METEOR@1.1.0.2` but these did not work. My project runs fine on the local host. What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you moved the project to a new directory, you need to change the app path in the mup.json file to the new directory.